# How to copy files from multiple folders on Azure DevOps CI?

Tags: azure-devops

In my yaml config file for Azure DevOps CI, I have a CopyFiles@2 task in order to stage files for PublishBuildArtifacts.  I want to (1) copy specific files from the root of my source directory, and (2) all the files from a specific folder.  I can copy the specific files successfully, but when I add the line for the specific folder, it fails. Here is the yaml snippet:

```yaml
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    contents:
      ?(binclash.log|init-tools.log)
      logs/**/*
    targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

The folders tree for the source looks like:

```
<repo root>
`-- binclash.log
`-- init-tools.log
`-- logs
    |-- debug
    `-- release
`-- src
    `-- ml.cs
```

As listed, this reports finding zero files.  However,
if I remove `logs/**/*` then it successfully finds and copies binclash.log and init-tools.log.  Is there some syntax related to quotes or line breaks that I am missing?

Comment: Can you share your folders tree and the logs from the build?

Comment: Here's a log with debug set to true: https://dnceng.visualstudio.com/public/_build/results?buildId=39866&view=logs

For this run the yaml was:
```
contents:
  msbuild.*
  binclash.log
  init-tools.log
```
and the folders tree looked like:
```
<repo root>
-- src
    |--ml.cs
-- msbuild.log
-- binclash.log
-- init-tools.log

Comment: What I was trying to describe above is having multiple lines under "contents".  Whenever I tried that it would result in zero files found to copy (with success status).  My current workaround is to have seperate tasks for each line I would have wanted under "contents".

Comment: What is your sources folder tree?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a very similar issue, where I wanted to use a specific folder as my build artifact.

When you target the folder directly: `logs/**/*`, it returns 0 results.

Instead try using `**/logs/**`

I have updated your snippet below:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    contents:
      ?(binclash.log|init-tools.log)
      **/logs/**
    targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

When I looked at your code, I noticed that you could simplify to:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    contents: '**/logs/**/?(binclash.log|init-tools.log)'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was an issue in the YAML.

The `contents` input accepts multiple patterns, each on a new line.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/copy-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml#inputs
>
> > The file paths to include as part of the copy. This string supports multiple lines of match patterns.

This means you need to use the multiline YAML syntax `|`. Your example should be:

```yaml
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    contents: |
      ?(binclash.log|init-tools.log)
      logs/**/*
    targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```